# Convert columns to list of dataframes and maintain names

Tags: r, list

I have a large `df` of column names containing response data to survey questions, and am able to do the the following:

1. Convert each column into a dataframe and store in list `x`
2. Create a separate list `y` containing tables of each dataframe

Dput:

```
df <- structure(list(`A question` = c("3", "4", "1", "3", "4", "3"), 
               `Some other question` = c("4", "4", "1", "3", "0", "3"), 
               `Other kind of question` = c("4", "3", "1", "4", "5", "4"
               )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
               ))
```

Code:

```
x <- lapply(df,as.data.frame)


y <- lapply(1:length(x),
            function(i){
              x[[i]] <- table(as.data.frame(x[[i]]))
            })
```

**My question is, how can I maintain the names for each df (as seen in `x`) when calling `lapply` to create `y`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear about the whether the OP needed a `list` of data.frames/tbl_df from each column or just the `table` output.  For the first case, we can use `split.default`

```
lst1 <- split.default(df, seq_along(df))
```

---

If we want to use `lapply`, instead of looping over the column, either loop over the column index or names

```
lapply(names(df), function(nm) df[nm])
```

---

If we need the `table`

```
lapply(df, table)
#$`A question`

#1 3 4 
#1 3 2 

#$`Some other question`

#0 1 3 4 
#1 1 2 2 

#$`Other kind of question`

#1 3 4 5 
#1 1 3 1
```

Or if it needs to be converted to `data.frame`, wrap with `as.data.frame`

```
lapply(df, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to working with lists and figured it was a pretty simple question, but couldn't find a similar question anywhere.

Comment: @Matt no problem.  I think you just need the `lapply(df, table)`.  When we loop over the whole data.frame, each column is a unit and it loops over the values of the column as  a `vector`

Comment: When using `lapply(df, table)`, how can I keep the class as `data.frame`?

Comment: @Matt Do you neeed `lapply(df, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again.